# Code now gives error wth new ADT

Tags: android

I've been using the following code in an XML layout file:

```
<!-- Copyright (C) 2008 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<!-- OK confirm and cancel buttons.  -->
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
        android:showDividers="beginning"
        android:paddingTop="16dip">

    <LinearLayout
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:measureWithLargestChild="true">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/leftSpacer"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                android:maxLines="2"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/ok_button"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/install"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="true"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/rightSpacer"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This created borderless buttons separated by a faint line as seen when installing an app in ICS or above or in the phone app. It used to even run fine in Froyo and Gingerbread however since updating to the latest version of ADT this XML layout file is giving compile error saying that button bar style and can only be used for API Level 11 and above.

As said before it used to compile fine, is there anything I can do to fix it. One hack is whenever I get the compile error is to increase the API level in the manifest, save it and then lower it again. Now ADT will not complain until I open the XML file again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however since updating to the latest version of ADT this XML layout file is giving compile error saying that button bar style and can only be used for API Level 11 and above.

That is because [those](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#buttonBarButtonStyle) [attributes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#buttonBarStyle) were only defined starting in API Level 11.

> is there anything I can do to fix it

Stop using it on API Level 10 and below, as it may give you problems that you have not yet seen. For example, you could move this layout to `res/layout-v11/`, and create another version of the same layout file in `res/layout/` that does not have these `style` attributes.

Comment: Yes I know the attributes are only defined in API 11, I was wondering why they were able to compile and work with the older ADT plugin.

Can I not copy the buttonBar attributes from the API?

Comment: @user1424720: "I was wondering why they were able to compile and work with the older ADT plugin" -- I can't answer that. "Can I not copy the buttonBar attributes from the API?" -- only if you can go back in time and update 100+ million phones.